# How to quickly break RSA encryption with very large numbers in Java with the Modulus and Exponent/Public Key

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I was given a task to make a program to break the RSA encryption with the modulus and public keys of both parties and the cipher text. I have found solutions that brute force to find the prime values that are multiplied for the modulus. However with the size of the numbers that I have to use, it doesn't seem like it can even finish processing.(the modulus is 30 digits long or so)

This is the example data we were given:

```
{
"alice": {
"modulus": "66056083785421544972111685239",
"publicKey": "38933338385103628492607145193"
},
"bob": {
"modulus": "71994651332404115788173195239",
"publicKey": "28763302913765661132800185637"
},
"cipherText": "5b8sot9g2168mp3nw51"
}
```

This is the solution I'm currently trying, using the Fermat algorithm to try and find the primes faster:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class ferr
{

    static BigInteger r1;
    static BigInteger r2;
    static BigInteger aliceModulus = new BigInteger("107182711767121947041078387099");

    public static void main (){
        System.out.println("running");
        ferr x = new ferr();
     x.fermat(aliceModulus);
    }


    public void fermat(BigInteger N)
    {
        BigInteger a = calcSQR(N);
        BigInteger b2 = (a.multiply(a).subtract(N));
        while(Square(b2) == false) {
            a = a.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            b2 = (a.multiply(a).subtract(N));
        } // end while
        r1 = a.subtract(calcSQR(b2));
        r2 = N.divide(r1);
        System.out.println("Roots = ("+ r1 +") , ("+ r2 +")");
    }

    public boolean Square(BigInteger N)
    {
        BigInteger sqRoot = calcSQR(N);
        if(sqRoot.multiply(sqRoot).equals(N)) {
            return true;
        } // end if
        else {
            return false;
        } // end else
    }

    public BigInteger calcSQR(BigInteger N)
    {
        if(N == BigInteger.ZERO || N == BigInteger.ONE) {
            return N; 
        } // end if
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
        BigInteger x;
        // Starting with x = N/2 avoids magnitude issues with x squared
        for(x = N.divide(two); x.compareTo(N.divide(x)) > 0; x = ((N.divide(x)).add(x)).divide(two)) {
            if(N.compareTo(x.multiply(x)) == 0) {
                return x;
            } // end if
            else { 
                return x.add(BigInteger.ONE); 
            } // end else
        } // end for-loop
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any faster solution to break the encryption? I've left this program running for a few hours and it's still no where near the end.

Comment: Consider using [yafu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yafu/) or [msieve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/). Also see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46695/how-to-factor-an-rsa256-public-key-with-yafu) on [crypto.se]

Comment: Hint: The primes you're seeking are closer to the square root of the 30 digit number than they are to 2.

Comment: An other hint: calculate the gcd of bob & alice modulus.

Comment: @WJS: For 96-Bit Prime? yafu did factorize it in < 1 second. This is NOT the problem here. And using Shor's algorithm is overkill here. And then both numbers share a common prime. This is not at all that hard here.

Comment: What do you mean by "rotating ciphers for transmitted ciphertext"? Do you have more information about this question than I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, Brute-Forcing the prime numbers is quite slow.
But there are easier ways.

1. Notice that you have two modulo, one for Bob, one for Alice.
   A trivial shot is to calculate the greatest common divisor of both:

   ```
   BigInteger bobM = new BigInteger("66056083785421544972111685239");
   BigInteger aliceM = new BigInteger("71994651332404115788173195239");
   System.out.println(bobM.gcd(aliceM));
   ```

   This will output `535006138814359`, which is one factor of both Bob and Alice.

   It might be pure luck that this works here, or it could be crafted that way by your instructor.
2. Use a faster factorization method.

   One of those is [Pollard's Rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), which is quite easy to implement.

   ```
   private static BigInteger pollardroh(BigInteger n, BigInteger x) {
       BigInteger y = x;
       BigInteger d = BigInteger.ONE;
       while (d.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
           x = x.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, n).add(BigInteger.ONE);
           y = y.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, n).add(BigInteger.ONE);
           y = y.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, n).add(BigInteger.ONE);
           d = x.subtract(y).abs().gcd(n);
       }
       return d;
   }
   ```

   Use it with a starting value of `x = BigInteger.TWO`.
   This will run for ~ 1 minute on my machine, and output `134567897654321` for Alice's modulo.

In the end, here are the factorization of both Alice & Bob's modulo:

```
Bob:
p1: 535006138814359
p2: 123467898764321

Alice:
p1: 535006138814359
p2: 134567897654321
```

The second primes look a bit suspicions, and not randomly selected at all.

Comment: Does the pollardroh rho algorithm guarantee a prime number as the output? or was it just the right one by coincidence?

Comment: You might need to start with a different `x` if it returns `n`. See the wikipedia page for some background information. Also, you can use a different function instead of `x^2+1 mod n`. For the modulus you gave, `(x<<1)+1 mod n` did even run faster.